# Create database triggers with sql-injection without stacked queries

Tags: sql, database, sql-injection

Currently im working on a research paper about sql-injection with RFID tags and Im curious if it is possible to create a database trigger with an sql injections if stacked queries are disabled. If stacked queries are enabled, of course it is easy (assuming you know the table layout), but what if they're disabled for security reasons.

The question is if it is *possible* to *create* a trigger, *given* that there is an SQL injection. Database does not matter, choose one that fits the needs.

Comment: Errr... SQL injection refers to the (possibly malicious) entry of SQL code into UI fields that were not created for that purpose, so that the entered SQL code is run by the host system, correct?

So, are you asking whether it's possible to create a trigger with the injected code, or whether it's possible to exploit a trigger?

Comment: Im asking if it is possible to create a trigger with injected code in case stacked queries are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

What database are looking for? In PostgreSQL every trigger calls a stored procedure. Inside a stored procedure, you can [execute dynamic queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) if you want. If you don't do anything against SQL injection, not using [quote_ident](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-string.html)() and/or quote_literal(), your procedure is vulnerable to SQL injection. That's your own choice.

Userinput can never be trusted, so why the worry about RFID input? It's input, therefore it can't be trusted.

Comment: I thing you misunderstand my question. The question is if it is possible to _create_ a trigger, _given_ that there is an SQL injection.